# Non spatial indexes in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, spatial

I'm trying to create a non-spatial index on two columns, one of which is a geometry column (SDO_GEOMETRY). It appears from the documentation that it is possible but I'm unable to create one.

An excerpt from the Oracle documentation:

> For each spatial column in a non-SPATIAL index except POINT columns, a
>   column prefix length must be specified. (This is the same requirement
>   as for indexed BLOB columns.) The prefix length is given in bytes.

Here's the query I'm trying to execute to create the index:

```
create index multiple_column_index on TestDB (ID, SHAPE) tablespace test;
```

The SHAPE column is the geometry column here. The error I'm receiving is:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02327: cannot create index on expression with datatype ADT
02327. 00000 -  "cannot create index on expression with datatype %s"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create an index on a non-indexable
       expression.
*Action:   Change the column datatype or do not create the index on an
       expression whose datatype is one of  VARRAY, nested table, object,
       LOB, or  REF.
```

I've not applied the column prefix here as I couldn't find any documentation that explains its usage.

Comment: Why do you need to add spatial column to regular index ?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve spatial data for a particular attribute. I want to see the performance by creating an index on spatial column and attribute column. Is this possible in Oracle? I can do this on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Oracle SDO supports special spatial operators or functions http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_operat.htm#SPATL110. This makes then useless in ordinar indexes - that's why Oracle does not allow to add them there (no =, <>, <,>, != can be used for ADT). You should create spatial index on SDO column.

Comment: Even if you could add a spatial column to a standard index, I fail to see how it would improve performance in any way.

Comment: You cannot add a spacial column ( an array of arrays ) to a b-tree.  Spatial indexes are R-Trees and the code for using them could not be more different.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to index a spatial column as a part of a B-Tree index.
If you have a spatial column on one of your tables — you have to create a spatial domain index on that column, in order to use spatial functions.

There's no other way to index those columns.

Spatial domain indexes are pretty complex - you got many interesting options when creating it.
One can achieve great performance configuring (and using) those indexes correctly.